# setting a breakpoint in a specific offset inside a function with 'gdb'

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am trying to set a breakpoint to  with 'gdb'.

From [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_28.html) I understood how to break specific line of function.
But I want to break specific offset of function.

```
0xb7eecfa8 <error+184>    mov    eax, dword ptr [ebx - 0x40]
0xb7eecfae <error+190>    sub    esp, 4
0xb7eecfb1 <error+193>    push   dword ptr [eax]

gdb> break error+184
Function "error+184" not defined.
```

Is there any command to break on `0xb7eecfa8 <error+184>`?
(except for just typing `b *0xb7eecfa8`)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is there any command to break on `<error+184>`

Both of these appear to do what you want:

```
b *(&error+184)
b *(error+184)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for dynamically-loaded libraries, while `b func_name_in_dylib` works